# CiImage Cant make by Using "CIColor" Constraint

Tags: ios, core-image

`let brownImage = CIImage(color:CIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.4, blue: 0.2))`

Error : error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: Why you think that this line is the cause of your crash? can you post all your crashlog?

Comment: I am practicing Core Image Actually trying to make a solid color Image from CIImae contractor than i will filter it and add to context but in first line i am getting error :P

Comment: This line don't crash by itself, so your problem is in another part of your code we need your crash log to see what is wrong

Comment: I am trying to convert it to a UiImage thn set it to imageView Like This   
  let brownImage = CIImage(color:CIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.4, blue: 0.2))

       " if let image:UIImage = UIImage(ciImage: brownImage) {
           
            self.imageView.image = image
        }" .  Naw image View Not set this image and no crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImage` has a `size`, `CIImage` has an `extent`. Check it - I'm guessing it's either `nil`, `CGSize.zero` or... `infinite`.

Using `CIImage(color:` is normally used for an *input* to a `CIFilter` like `CIConstantColorGenerator`, which has *no* `CIImage` input.

In other words, you are using an "apple" to try to create an "orange".

Based on your comments, I'm thinking you *do not* want to use Core Image at all. If all you are doing is trying to fill a `UIView` with a (easily adjusted by sliders) color and then end up with a `UIImage of it, consider:

- Using a `UIView` and it's background color set using either RGB or HSV sliders and their `UIColor` values
- Creating a `UIImage from said view like so:

  ```
  func createImage(from aView:UIView) -> UIImage {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: aView.frame.width, height: aView.frame.height), true, 1)
      aView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return image!
  }
  ```

Of course, if you are trying to do something else, edit your question and I'll do my best to help!